# Dual monitors: auto hide on only main monitor

Tags: unity, launcher

Is there a way to set up the Unity launcher (Ubuntu 16.04) such that it autohides on the primary monitor, but is always visible on the others?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to configure the Unity launcher in this manner, no.